# Why is this RegEx.Replace failing, even though I'm matching the string?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Am I understanding how RegEx.Replace works in C#/.NET? I want this:

> Test: String

To become this:

> Test String

```
var cleanString = Regex.Replace("Test: String", @"^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$", "");
```

Yet it cleanString evaluates to:

> Test: String

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'm getting a regex validation string from a third party source, so I can either use that regex validation string or somehow figure out the valid characters in the regex validation string, and loop through an invalid character array. This is why I chose to do regex, which I never usually use.

Comment: why would you use a regex for that?

Comment: You attempted to solve a problem with a RegEx: now you have 2 problems!

Comment: I've added why I'm using RegEx (because I'm going off a RegEx validation string provided to me and that may change), edit: was this downvoted simply because of RegEx?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Your RegEx matches the two individual words in `Test: String`.. but it won't match the colon. So it looks like this: `Test`: `String`. Do you just want to remove the colon? Because that regex won't do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Regex.Replace` won't do what you're trying to do.  The regex pattern used in `Regex.Replace` needs to match on the bits of the string that you want to replace.

The string validation pattern you're trying to use matches only a valid string.  You can use `Regex.IsMatch` with this pattern to check whether or not a string is valid, but it won't, and can't, show you which characters in the string prevent the match from succeeding.

You need to use a pattern that matches bad characters.  A first stab for this situation would be `[^\w\*\-\d\(\)\s\$]+`.  This will match any character not allowed by the validation string, but is still not good enough.  For example, it won't match non-digit characters between the optional parentheses, and it won't enforce a single pair of matching parentheses.  When you start to consider all the possible ways a string could be invalid as single Regex pattern to strip out invalid characters will quickly become unworkable.

Comment: I misunderstood Regex.Replace, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
Dictionary<string,string> whiteList = new Dictionary<string,string>();
//populate whitelist
public StringBuilder cleanString(string dirtyInput)  
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
    foreach(char in dirtyInput)    
    {  
        if(null == dirtyInput.get(char)  
        {  
             sb.append(char);  
        }
    }  
    return sb;

}
```

may be a bit off as my Java may be bleeding over.